# How can I calculate the percentage of occurrence of particular value in each column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with counts in each column (there are 20 columns), and I have calculated the percentage of `0's` that appear in each column for the filtered list of employees.

Here are the simplified table definitions and data that I used to test. I have a table `EmployeeNotificationCounts`:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeNotificationCounts 
(
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    Notification1 INT NOT NULL,
    Notification2 INT NOT NULL,
    Notification3 INT NOT NULL,
    Notification4 INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (1, 1, 15, 0, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (3, 1, 15, 0, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (4, 2, 3, 6, 0, 15)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (5, 1, 15, 0, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (6, 1, 15, 0, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (7, 2, 18, 0, 0, 25)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (8, 1, 15, 0, 0, 5)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (9, 2, 0, 14, 0, 35)
INSERT INTO EmployeeNotificationCounts VALUES (10, 1, 15, 0, 0, 5)
```

I want to get a result like below in percentage for 0's in each notification for all employees of type = 2:

```
Notification1  Notificatio2  Notification3  Notification4
---------------------------------------------------------
10              70            100             0
```

I have a query that does this job

```
SELECT 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeNotificationCounts 
      WHERE Notification1 = 0 AND EmployeeTypeId = 2) * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS IncompleteChart0Percentage,
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeNotificationCounts 
      WHERE Notification2 = 0 AND EmployeeTypeId = 2) * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS IntComm0Percentage,
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeNotificationCounts 
      WHERE Notification3 = 0 AND EmployeeTypeId = 2) * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS PTComm0Percentage,
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeNotificationCounts 
      WHERE Notification4 = 0 AND EmployeeTypeId = 2) * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS PendingBilling0Percentage
FROM 
    EmployeeNotificationCounts ENC
WHERE
    ENC.EmployeeTypeId = 2
```

I have this query that gets me the result as desired. But, can this be optimized for larger databases? In production, this table might have thousands of records. I haven't run this in production yet, just wanted to be sure if the percentage calculation statements can be written differently. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of writing this in a slightly more compact way which you may prefer as there's many columns is to use `iif`

```
select
    Avg(Iif(Notification1=0,100.0,0)) IncompleteChart0Percentage,
    Avg(Iif(Notification2=0,100.0,0)) IntComm0Percentage,
    Avg(Iif(Notification3=0,100.0,0)) PTComm0Percentage,
    Avg(Iif(Notification4=0,100.0,0)) PendingBilling0Percentage
 From EmployeeNotificationCounts
 Where EmployeeTypeId = 2
```

Comment: I like this one just because I have 35 columns and this query made it look more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Just another option

```
Select Notification1 = avg(case when Notification1 = 0 then 100.0 else 0 end) 
      ,Notification2 = avg(case when Notification2 = 0 then 100.0 else 0 end) 
      ,Notification3 = avg(case when Notification3 = 0 then 100.0 else 0 end) 
      ,Notification4 = avg(case when Notification4 = 0 then 100.0 else 0 end) 
 From EmployeeNotificationCounts
 Where ENC.EmployeeTypeId = 2
```

**Returns**

```
Notification1   Notification2   Notification3   Notification4
10.000000       70.000000       100.000000      0.000000
```

**NOTE:**
If you'd rather 70 as 0.7 for example, change `100.0` to `1.0`

Comment: just  you may  want to add `where ENC.EmployeeTypeId = 2`

Comment: @eshirvana Thanks for the catch :)